# present continuous vs present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-continuous

Do you think these sentences have the same meaning?

> "We **have increasingly been being** exposed to a number of new hazardous chemical and biological agents and therefore...."
>
> "We **are increasingly being**  exposed to a number of new hazardous chemical and biological agents and therefore...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have increasingly been being exposed

While this may be technically correct ("been being" is jarring), what you'll hear/read more usually is this:

> We have increasingly been exposed

This means that "over some time period in the past, we have been increasingly exposed", and that the increasing exposure may or may not be continuing now - but the strong default assumption would be that it is continuing now, since if you said

> We were increasingly exposed

this would mean "we aren't being increasingly exposed" anymore.

> We are increasingly being exposed

This means that *now*, we are being increasingly exposed, whereas before now, we were not being increasingly exposed.  (Previously, we may have been simply exposed, but not increasingly so).

Comment: Thanks.My previous sentence is "The interesting  thing  about  poisoning is its diversity ,especially since the world has become industrialized," so I assume that I should use We have increasingly been exposed.Do you agree?

Comment: I agree.  It's what I would use.